# Is square root of a non-negative random variable also a random variable?

Tags: measure-theory, random-variables

Let $X$ be a non-negative random variable and $Y=\sqrt{X}$

Is it true that $Y$ will also be a random variable?

Any hints please?

Comment: My guess is random, but with a different distribution.

Comment: https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat414/node/128

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**. Note that $\sqrt{\cdot} \colon [0,\infty) \to [0,\infty)$ is monotone, hence measurable.